# Why does my query to VersionOne API using find does not return expected results?

Tags: api, rest, versionone

I'm trying to use the VersionOne [rest-1.v1/Data](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Documentation/API/Endpoints/rest-1.v1%2F%2FData) endpoint to [find](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Documentation/API/Queries/find) all stories with the string `9.00.00.01` in a particular field. Here's the query (newlines added for readability):

```
<Server Base URI>/rest-1.v1/Data/Story
    ?sel=Number,Custom_FixedinVersions
    &find=9.00.00.01
    &findin=Custom_FixedinVersions
```

This is returning results which do not show the `9.00.00.01` string in the queried field. For example:

```
<Asset href="/rest-1.v1/Data/Story/60560" id="Story:60560">
    <Attribute name="Number">B-06248</Attribute>
    <Attribute name="Custom_FixedinVersions">8.10.00.00-01</Attribute>
</Asset>
```

What's wrong with my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `find` feature of the rest-1.v1 API uses the same underlying capabilities as the [Advanced Search](http://community.versionone.com/Help-Center/Version101/Current/Introduction-to-VersionOne/Search) feature. Therefore, it has the [same limitations](http://community.versionone.com/Help-Center/Common-Questions/Search_does_not_work_-_No_results_from_search) as the VersionOne application. Namely, punctuation marks are treated as single-character terms and are excluded from the search query. So the above term `9.00.00.01` is treated as `9 00 00 01` where the search engine matches any of the space-separated values. Therefore, `8.10.00.00-01` matches both `00` and `01` terms.